# How To Read C# API From Java Background

Tags: c#

I come from a Java background and have been using C# for the last year - So far the API docs I use are at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx).  I tend to use the lightweight C# docs.

What annoys me about that is that I don't see one page with details of the class, a list of members, a list of methods and properties like I would with a Java API definition.

Is this possible?

Comment: Real c# developers memorize the properties and members of the entire .net framework .. ;)

Comment: Jon Skeet memorizes the properties and members of the entire .net framework .. ;) 
Fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The closest you'll get is when when you click on the members link for the class and retrieve a summary list of all the members (methods, operators and properties) with more in depth details linked.

I kind of prefer this way of docs because you can fit in more information without having the pages be too verbose. Javadoc pages for a class tend to be huge, and I don't like spraining my *scroll finger*. ;)

Answer (score 1):

MSDN is organized differently to javadoc pages.

Welcome :)

Comment: @Dave Markle: subjective opinion is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the MSDN Library with a browser is self-inflicted punishment.  [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373&DisplayLang=en) and install it on your own machine so that navigating to the details of a class member is instant.  The index you'll get is *very* useful as well.

Comment: I agree that the VS2005/2008 local help system is pretty good. Unfortunately, in Help 3 (VS2010) the index has disappeared, as well as the member filter... and the search results presentation really sucks. I really hate the new documentation system :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're talking about.  If you look at the left bar of the link you sent, click on "Collection(T) Members" and that includes all of the methods and properties in one page.

Comment: I understand the request just fine. Look at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html - everything in one spot, without another (the 10th?) level of nested navigation. Unfortunately I don't think there's an equivalent for MSDN..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Object Browser in Visual Studio (if that is the IDE you are using.)